# What are the differences between "When did she move in?" & "When has she moved in?"

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

I am a bit confused!

I am not sure whether the native English speakers choose to use "**When did she move in?**" or "**When has she moved in?**".

If we use simple past tense, we imply that the specific time in the past is important. For example, "**She moved in 2 months ago**"

If we use present perfect tense, we imply that the specific time in the past is not important or we don't need a specific time. For example, "**She has moved in recently**".

So, my question is

when you the native speakers say "**When has she moved in?**" meaning that you don't care about specific time or you don't need an answer with a specific time?

when you the native speakers say "**When did she move in?**" meaning that you care about specific time or you need an answer with a specific time?

Comment: @WS2, I am asking the question in simple past & in present perfect. What are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We rarely use the present perfect with *when* questions. As the Original Poster notes, the present perfect represents an indefinite time of an indefinite event. The word *when* conflicts with part of the meaning of present perfect constructions.The word *when* requires an indication of a *specific* time from the speaker. So, for this reason,  we rarely use *when* and the present perfect in the same question.

The exception to this is when we are using the present perfect to indicate a time starting in the past and running up the the present moment. In such situations we might observe *since when* or *when .... since* type questions:

- Since when have you been waiting?

We also sometimes use the present perfect with *when* if we want to imply that there there *was* no event or situation to assign a specific time to:

- When has a woman (ever) been President of the USA?

Comment: I've deleted my off-topic comments.

Answer (score 0):

With 'when', you need Simple Past for this specific question:
When did she move in? A week ago. / Yesterday.

Without a specific time, Present Perfect can be used : They've moved in, and are still in the process of unpacking.

'when' can be used with Present Perfect this way:

When have I ever insulted you? (Have I ever insulted you?)

Comment: Your last sentence isn't supported (assuming Gricean maxims are holding) by [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moved+in+recently%2Chas+moved+in+recently&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoved%20in%20recently%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What exactly are you saying here? (I don't know if it's just me, but on frequent occasions I don't understand your comments).*Moved in recently* would presumably include both present and perfect instances - e.g. *(they) recently moved in* and *(they have) recently moved in*. And I don't trust Google Ngrams. They can be affected by so many factors. This one, for example, is probably a reflection of nothing more than the fact of greatly increased housing mobility since the early 20th century.

Comment: There are plenty of other ways you can use *when* with the perfect - *When, in the last week, have I had the opportunity?*

Comment: @WS2 Right. I provided one example, to demonstrate.

Comment: @WS2 The version I was addressing was 'Without a specific time, [when]  is used with Present Perfect'. Gricean maxims indicate that this should be used to mean  'Without a specific time, [when] must be used with Present Perfect'. //  Look at the flatline for 'has moved in recently'; differencing the graphs (easy when one's a flatline) gives in this case {uses of 'moved in recently' less uses of 'has moved in recently'}. I should have included 'have moved in recently', which is about 20% of the 'moved in recently' total in 2000. The simple past still seems to be favoured.

Comment: If you do raw Google searches for "they have moved in recently" vs "they moved in recently", you may be surprised. (You can check that the examples are relevant.) // I don't trust Google Ngrams totally myself, but I think a lot of people mistakenly believe that their subjective opinions are more reliable as an indicator of how English is used.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Unfortunately, EFL learners see grammar differently from native speakers, and it also depends on what exam they're preparing for. Recently is used with both tenses, but Americans use Simple Past more loosely than in the UK.

Comment: Sorry, Cathy; that was a two-comment comment answering WS2. //   Changing 'is' (implies 'must' according to the Gricean maxim of quantity) to 'can' gets rid of the problem. // If you're an EFL teacher, please define your terms if you ever get a chance to answer on the ill-defined 'phrasal verbs' and 'prepositional verbs'. I think there's a global EFL usage, which is by no means the only one. Though I think the topic has been done to death here.

Comment: I think you'll find I generally concentrate on giving an easily comprehensible answer, and avoid complexities of terminology that don't help a person to learn a language. Useful terminology helps explain grammar, and of course I use it if I think it will make my answer clearer,  but obscure issues are better left to linguists, not me.